# Not complains when type is not correct when extended interface

Tags: typescript

I tested this snippet [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIgDYE8BycC2KA3gFDLnIgEQBcyAzmFKAOYkC%20JJoksiKAWSwAVCIwBMyCAA9IIACb00mXNWRFkZCnBa1KAV3wAjaBy4YIYZJEYBGOumx5CAbi4IA9iEYNLou8gAvMgAFABuDirOEACUQQB86lrkNmC2Qchhycie3h4WAHQYHiwhqbYxZiQWVqnidEL%20YJLBpBSU1HQA5HVdADTZOnriA5wk9H5iaWVT4pVAA)

```
interface OnlyName {
    name: string
}

interface MyTest2 extends OnlyName { 
    age: number
}

let test1: OnlyName;

const setTest1 = (v: OnlyName) => {
    test1 = v
    console.log(test1)
}

let test2: MyTest2 = {
    name: 'test2',
    age: 2,
}

setTest1(test2)
```

I expected setTest1() will complain because `setTest1()` only allows `OnlyName` as parameter, but `MyTest2` is passed, it works.

Why it not complains and is there are ways to allow only `OnlyName`?

Comment: No, typescript has [structural type system](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#starting-out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Aleksey L said, this is because of structural type system.
If You pass literal object to `setTest1`, TS will complain:

```js
setTest1({
    name: 'test2',
    age: 2, //Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'age' does not exist...
})
```

You can find more about excess property checking [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks)